# Is $e^{ix}$ a travelling wave?

Tags: complex-analysis

Sorry, if my question is too stupi, but is
$$
e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)
$$
a travelling wave?

---

A travelling wave (to the right in $x$-direction with speed $\omega/k$) is something like
$$
u(x,t)=e^{i(kx-\omega t)}
$$
which is some "helix" winding around the $x$-axis in three dimensional space.

Now I am wondering if one can already see $e^{ix}$ as travelling wave.

Answer (score 2):

$e^{ix}$ is constant in time.  So no, it's not "travelling".

Comment: I have another question. In this link http://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys2130/phys2130_sp12/lecture_pdfs/Class%2027%20uncertainty%20and%20more%20wave%20equations.pdf ,on the first page, there are shown complex exponentials and on the right side some pictures in different colors... but the pictures do not fit to the formulas, aren't they?

Comment: I assume the pictures are supposed to be either the real or imaginary components of the wavefunctions vs either the position or time.  Not having any axis labels it's hard to tell which, but each of the 4 graphs (real vs position, imaginary vs position, etc) will look like sinusoids.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thanks!